# The meaning of "floored" in: "he was floored when they told him he was 'going viral'"

Tags: word-meaning, british-english

I need to confess I am a [**Limahl**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limahl) fan and my feeling goes with [**this story.**](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/the-neverending-story-of-viral-hit-the-never-ending-story-a-challenging-qa-with-singer-limahl-052856665.html)

It's a bit long article, so that please forgive me if you need to read to the line I would like to lead to, which is

> Limahl, whose real name is Chris Hamill, confesses that he’s never seen Stranger Things (though he plans to enjoy a binge-watching session soon), and **he says he was floored** when his nephew informed him that he was “going viral.”

According to Merriam Unabridged, the verb floor has 3 definitions.

> 1 a :  to cover with a floor :  furnish with flooring
>   
>   b :  to form the floor of
>
> 2
>   :  to strike down or lay level with the floor :  knock down; broadly :  **silence,** defeat
>
> 3
>   :  to put, send, force, or display on or toward the floor

None of these seems fit, but I found the bold verb which I think would be the one. Would the line "to be floored" mean "to be silenced" or rather "go to the point where he can not utter a word ( by a sudden news )".

**P.S**

### **By the way, is this way of use of the verb or word "floor" usual and ordinary in Britain or even in the U.S?**

Kindly confirm, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster's online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floor) lists definition #2 of "floor" (as a verb):

> **2a** : to knock or bring down
>
> **b** : flabbergast, dumbfound

It is **b** that is being used in this quote.

I don't know about British English, but this expression was common decades ago (at *least*) in the US. I don't know if it dropped out of currency completely or not, but it seems to be getting very popular lately. A 17-year-old I know had not heard it until this month, and she found it very humorous. We laugh about it every time we hear it now, which seems to be every couple of days.

Comment: Oh, so that it was American expression. ( Yeah, because the article is from Yahoo America it would be so. ). Anyway, thank you. Let me wait a little bit before I choose.

Comment: I'm so glad the theme of the Never Ending Story reached to young lads even in the U.S after the release of the file about 40 years ago. I, in the 40's, always loved this song. FYI. ^^.

Comment: I think definition 2a started in boxing (as in 'he knocked his opponent to the floor' or 'he was knocked to the floor by his opponent), but I can't find any source to support that.

Comment: @KentaroTomono The verb *floor* in this sense is not confined to AmE. In fact, it's pretty neutral – the dictionaries I've checked don't label it as belonging to AmE or BrE.

Comment: @userr2684291 Thanks. Kindly be informed the reason why I had assumed this verb would've been British is only because that Lihmal is British. But the luckier thing I could understand today is, the verb is a bit outdated...Anyway thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Lorel C.: Looks pretty consistent to me; it's even increased in the last few decades (you can click on each chart to see actual instances; some are false positives, but most correspond to the sense at issue): https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=77756250. The phenomenon you're experiencing might be explained by this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baader%E2%80%93Meinhof_effect (it often happens to me when I become aware of / learn a new word).

Comment: @userr2684291 Ahm....well...yes, it is certainly increasing. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: @userr2684291 well maybe it's the old phenomenon of "you see it all the time and don't notice, but the first time you notice it, then it's everywhere", but I think it was earlier this month, this 17-y.o. in my family reported that her friend had used the funniest expression ("floored"), which she thought the friend had invented. I told her no, people used to say that all the time, and since then we have heard it like 6 times. I think it made its way into some internet teen "meme", and pretty soon we'll all be sick of hearing the old tired expression, "I was floored!"

Comment: @userr268429 Thanks for putting a name to the "phenomenon". Who would have thought that the Baader-Meinhof gang would have made such a contribution to science? (Note to comment police: 10-4 I'm done.)

Comment: I'm British, and I know exactly what 'floored' means in this context, and would have done at any time in the last 50 years.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I will be glad if you could make an answer. The original title of the question had "could be British English", so you are welcomed to have your answer.